# Disable Chrome from checking SSL certificates completely

Tags: ubuntu, google-chrome, ssl, certificate

I have to enter a website that has an invalid certificate and I can't because Chrome won't let me (to protect me, how hilarious!).

I don't want or need to be protected, so I just want to completely disable the SSL feature to continue working without wasting more time.

Any tips?

Comment: Add the certificate to the user's certificate store and it should solve your problem.  If you disable SSL you wouldn't be able to connect to the website at all

Comment: Can you tell me how to do that?

Comment: What install self-signed certificates? what step in the process are you stuck on?

Comment: i dont know where to get the certificate or where to install it

Answer (score 1):

In chrome, if you get an invalid certificate warning, you can still continue if you choose to. When you get the message "Your connection is not private", click on "Advanced". Then "Proceed to .... (unsafe)".

Note you cannot disable "the ssl feature". SSL is one of the most important security features the web has to offer. Whether or not to use SSL is determined by the site, not by you or your browser. If the site you are going to has an invalid SSL cert, it's possible that you are not actually on the site you think you are on, so you should be careful when entering in passwords or personal information. The browser is trying to protect you by warning you that the SSL certificate is not verified. But all browsers let you continue anyway if you want to.

This may help too: [Continuing beyond Chrome SSL Warnings](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/26049/chrome-ssl-warning-you-cannot-proceed-because-the-website-operator-has-request)

Comment: for some reason i can't continue in FF or chrome in ubuntu

Comment: What does the error message say regarding the cert? I added a link which may help.

Comment: danger doesnt work, its the same error it gives to everyone i just cant find the proceed anyways option anywhere

Comment: This is only true is the site isn't using HSTS. If the site has sent the HSTS header, then you CAN NOT proceed. That's the point of HSTS.

Comment: well, i will have to sell my computer then.

Answer (score 1):

Sadly Google does not give the user an easy way to add a Certificate to the list of trusted certificates. To get rid of the message you should add the certificate to your OS's trusted certificates. How this can be achieved is however system dependent.

This is the steps that should work for Ubuntu (Copied from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7580508/getting-chrome-to-accept-self-signed-localhost-certificate) question, more info there):

1. Click the lock icon with an x
2. Choose Certificate Information
3. Go to details tab
4. Click on Export... (save as a file)
5. Now, the following command will add the certificate (where YOUR_FILE is your exported file):
   `certutil -d sql:$HOME/.pki/nssdb -A -t "P,," -n YOUR_FILE -i YOUR_FILE`

To list all your certificates, run the following command:
`certutil -d sql:$HOME/.pki/nssdb -L`

If nothing helps you can always just choose to ignore the certificate issue. Notice howerver that this means you will **loose all protection from man-in-the-middle-attacks!** If you still decide to solve your problem this way, having to do two extra clicks to proceed to the website every time can get quite annoying. To get around this in Chrome you can set a time in 
chrome://flags/#remember-cert-error-decisions, leadings to the Error being shown only once every three months.

Happy Hacking,
Nuwanda

Comment: I added the ubuntu tag when i asked my question. I dont care about the attacks and i cannot make any decisions so its pretty useless to remember them.

Comment: I am sorry, i didn't notice that tag, I edited my answer.

Comment: Sadly `chrome://flags/#remember-cert-error-decisions` was removed see here [link](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/8gJ3uMHWta8) I have to administer 1000 routes and the is slowing me down.

Comment: This is an old question, that has already been answered. It also has absolutely nothing to do with routes. Please post a new question, making sure to describe your problem as accurate as you can. In addition to that please be aware, that chrome://flags/#remember-cert-error-decisions is **not** the solution for this question. It is a workaround and should _never_ be used for extended periods of time or in a production environment.